# How to create a simple animated button in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt5, qpushbutton, qt6, qpropertyanimation

I don't understand the syntax of `QPropertyAnimation` at all, I looked at several "similar" questions, but I couldn't figure it out.

Could you write a simple example of a button that, when pressed, will gradually reduce its width to zero, so that one icon remains from it, and after pressing it again, it returns to its previous width.

I read the `QPropertyAnimation` documentation, but it seemed too incomprehensible to me, and I couldn't figure out the questions on the forum where this method also appeared.

Comment: It seems you're asking for a tutorial, a ready-made code. Have you tried watching or reading tutorials? check out [Parwiz Forogh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8daw2I0Zrw) on youtube, he made several tutorials on qt animation, give it a go, write some code, and when you run into a specific problem with it, post it here detailing everything did, have and tried. Good luck!

Comment: Can you implement this without animation, just changing the width? If not, start with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doc https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpropertyanimation.html you have a similar example where the position changes. I do not clearly see what confusion there can be. QPropertyAnimation animates the property of an object from a start value to an end value.

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(tr("Animated Button"), this);
QPropertyAnimation *anim = new QPropertyAnimation(button, "pos", this);
anim->setDuration(10000);
anim->setStartValue(QPoint(0, 0));
anim->setEndValue(QPoint(100, 250));
anim->start();
```

Apparently, width is a property of QPushButton, which it inherits from QWidget: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#width-prop. So, from the example in the doc, you can simply replace the three values prop, start value and end value.